# Best game engine based on python

Tags: python, gui, game-development

I learnt python till oop and a bit more.

I searched the internet about python game engines. But it recommends framework instead of gui based engine.

Is there any good gui game engine which python is the game scripting language.

**My requirements are:**

- Simple as PyGame (if possible)
- The game logic is programming and adding sprites, sounds, and others like saving, etc are GUI.
- Not compulsory for any sort of inbuilt image,sound and other editors except the main needed editors.
- No need of any sort of 3D.
- Lightweight and must support 2GB Ram, 32bit and Slow computers (Not too slow).

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints. Especially, what features should it support? What is your price limit? Any license considerations?

Comment: This is probably not what you want but Godot engine has python-like scripting language.  But it is _not_ python, just a superficially quite similar language.

Comment: @Ott Toomet I know Godot and I have used it before in a different pc, but It is my relatives pc. My PC is not supporting Godot.